# C# Group results from List<T> into another List<T2> with selected fields

Tags: c#, wpf, linq

I was wondering if there's a simpler way to do this using LINQ or some other way...

I want to extract, from a List, all rows, grouping them by a particular field and storing the result in another different, like a List containing the grouped, not repeated, result of the search parameter.

Here's an example:

```
public class CustomObj
{
    public int DOC { get; set; }
    public string Desc { get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }
}

public class Worker()
{
   public void DoWork()
   {
      List<CustomObj> objs = new List<CustomObj>();
      objs.Add(new CustomObj(1, "Type1", "Name1"));
      objs.Add(new CustomObj(1, "Type2", "Name1"));
      objs.Add(new CustomObj(2, "Type2", "Name2"));
      objs.Add(new CustomObj(3, "Type1", "Name1"));
      objs.Add(new CustomObj(3, "Type2", "Name1"));
      objs.Add(new CustomObj(3, "Type3", "Name1"));

      // HERE'S WHAT I'D LIKE TO DO
      // NOTE THAT THIS IS NOT A CORRECT FORMATED FUNCTION
      List<int> docs = objs.GroupBy(o => o.DOC).Select(o => o.DOC).ToList<int>();
   }
}
```

At the end my docs List should look like this

```
docs[0] = 1
docs[1] = 2
docs[2] = 3
```

In my current project I have, so far, 10 different objects, and I'm going to have to do this to all of them. Of course I'd like to avoid writing extensive functions to each one.

So if there's no other way at least I would like to know.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about:

```
List<int> docs = objs.Select(o => o.DOC).Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: Ran a couple of tests and seems to work perfectly. Just had to add the OrderBy to have an ordered result. Thanks a bunch, you just saved me a lot of work!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Or, if you want to use GroupBy:

```
  var docs = objs.GroupBy(o => o.DOC).Select(o => o.Key).ToList();
```

Comment: It seems to work as well as the answer from Janiels... but since I tested his first, I accepted that one... sorry, but thanks a lot for the answer. It's nice to know that there's more than one way to achieve the same result!